# SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard with SSIS Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have SQL server 2008 R2 Standard installed with SSIS. I need a SSIS feature that is only available with the enterprise edition. Is it possible to upgrade SSIS only to enterprise while keeping the database install as is (standard)?

Comment: You could install Developer Edition for pure development needs, but for production you need to fully upgrade you instance. SSIS itself is a feature of MS SQL Server (2k5 +), not an independent tool.

Answer (score 5):

No. The only way to license SSIS enterprise features is to get SQL Server Enterprise Edition.  Your other option is to implement the functionality in some other way such as a stored procedure, TVF, or .Net code embedded in the SSIS package (e.g. a script task).

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain that you will not be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is included with SQL Server.  If you need SSIS Enterprise, you need to purchase SQL Server Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone has said, no, you can't upgrade SSIS to Enterprise and leave the rest as Standard, it doesn't work that way. If you can't implement the functionality another way like @concernedoftunbridgewells suggested, you could look at 3rd party tools to see if they can meet the need..like Attunity (fast Oracle data flow connections), Or Cozy ROC. They may be a bit cheaper than going for the Enterprise Lic. They also offer a lot of free SSIS tools. Good Luck.